# как правильно применить функцию resize библиотеки graphicsmagick?

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения, resize

Необходимо сохранить одну и ту же фотографию в базу данных в разных размерах. В `newPhoto` сохраняется оригинальный размер фотографии, а в `previewPhoto` пытаюсь сохранить ту же самую фотографию, но размером меньше. Использую пакет gm. Как в моем случае правильно применить функцию `resize`, что указывать в качестве аргументов. В настоящий момент ничего не происходит и не выводит ошибок.
схема фотографии:

```
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    filePhoto: String,
    previewPhoto: String,
    standartPhoto: String,
});
```

функция сохранения файла фото:

```
app.post('/addPhoto',function (req, res) {
    var phts = req.files.filePhotos;
    if (!req.files){}
    var photoName = './public/uploads/'+Date.now()+phts.name;
    phts.mv(photoName);
    var data = req.body;
    data.filePhoto = photoName;
     try{
        new ExifImage({image: phts.data}, function (error, exifData) {
            if(error){} else{
                var newPhoto = new Photo(data);
                newPhoto.save(function(err, temp){
                    if(err){}
                });
                    var previewName = './public/uploads/preview'+Date.now()+phts.name;
                phts.mv(previewName);
                data.filePhoto = previewName;
                var previewPhoto = gm(photoName).resize(15, 15).write(previewName, function (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                });

            }
        });
    }catch (error) {}
  } ) ;
```